# Array of Characters not updated properly java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, character

I am trying to make pong in a terminal on windows in java.
I have an array of characters (called board) and the paddle positions are updated by the following code

```
public void movePaddles()
{
  int inp = 0;
  try
  {
     inp = System.in.read();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     return;
  }
  int olr = rtop;
  int oll = ltop;
  switch(inp)
  {
     case 'w':
        ltop -=1;
        break;
     case 's':
        ltop += 1;
        break;
     case 'i':
        rtop -= 1;
        break;
     case 'k':
        rtop += 1;
        break;
  }
  updatePaddle('L',oll);
  updatePaddle('R',olr);
}
public void updatePaddle(char side,int oldtop)
{
  int edge = 0;
  int top = 0;
  // Leave 1 char of space
  if (side == 'L')
  {
     edge = 1;
     top = ltop;
  }
  else if (side == 'R')
  {
     edge = y-2;
     top = rtop;
  }
  for (int i = oldtop;i < paddleSize+1;i++)
  {
        board[i][edge] = ' ';
  }
  for (int i = top;i < paddleSize+2;i++)
  {
        board[i][edge] = paddleChar;
  }
}
```

What ends up happening is that the paddles disappear when moving down, making the game unplayable. What am I doing wrong?

(full code on github at https://github.com/Tookmund/Text-Pong)

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did try debugging my program before I posted my question but not properly it appears.

Basically I needed to add the value of the current location (top/oldtop) so that the loop would not exit prematurely because i was initially bigger that the paddleSize.